# How to move all elements from a list to an array or a vector or anything else

Tags: c++, list

I am making a c++ problem in witch I have to write a function that takes a list. The problem is that I don't understand lists at all because I don't know how to work with pointers or iterators. Is there any way I can move all elements from that list to an array or a vector? It would make my life easier.

Comment: Understanding how to work with pointers and iterators will also make your life very much easier! hehe

Answer (score 5):

> How to move all elements from a list to an array or a vector or anything else

You use the [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) function.

```
std::list<foo> l;
std::vector<foo> r;
r.reserve(std::size(l));
std::move(std::begin(l), std::end(l), std::back_inserter(r));
```

If the objects you move are not of fundamental types, moving, rather than copying, will often be a lot faster.

If you have the option to create the `vector<foo>` on the go, use [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)s

```
std::list<foo> l;
std::vector<foo> r(std::move_iterator(std::begin(l)), std::move_iterator(std::end(l)));
```

Comment: I didn't realise move had that overload, thanks!

Comment: @Objectobject You're welcome! It's strangely unusual to see that function used here on SO. I like it a lot.

Comment: And additionally. Starting with C++17 and CTAD, you can omit the ````<foo>```` after ````std::vector````. So, something like: ````std::vector r(std::move_iterator(std::begin(l)), std::move_iterator(std::end(l)));````. Anyway. Best answer

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
std::vector<T> v;
std::copy(std::begin(l), std::end(l), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Where `l` is your "list" (by which I assume you mean C style array) and `T` is the type of things in your list. Note this copies the elements rather than moving them, but if they are basic types they cannot be moved anyway.

As pointed out by Ted Lyngmo, std::vector actually has a constructor for this already:

```cpp
std::vector<T> v(std::begin(l), std::end(l));
```

Comment: In this case: `std::vector<T> v(std::begin(l), std::end(l));` would be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::copy` to copy from one container (your list) to another container (your vector):

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::copy(std::begin(list), std::end(list), std::back_inserter(vec));

    for (auto element: vec) {
        std::cout << element << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/73rj494f4

---

You can also manually copy elements from one container to the other. However, while this is maybe easier to understand, it is not as elegant:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(list.size());  // Optional.

    // Copy the elements manually
    for (auto element: list) {
        vec.push_back(element);
    }

    // Manually print the elements in vec.
    for (auto element: vec) {
        std::cout << element << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/faf8ahr75